# nativescript-angular - radcalendar - keep today's date selected

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I've implemented RadCalendar in my Nativescript Angular project.

```
<GridLayout>
    <ScrollView class="page">
        <StackLayout class="home-panel">
            <Button text="Clear" (tap)="onClearTap()"></Button>
            <RadCalendar height="1000px" [viewMode]="viewMode" #mainCalendar
                [selectionMode]="selectionMode" [eventSource]="calEvents"
                (loaded)="calendarLoaded($event)"
                [eventsViewMode]="eventsViewMode"
                [selectedDate]="selectedDate" [displayedDate]="selectedDate">
            </RadCalendar>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

From the constructor, I'm adding an event for today's date.

```
constructor() {
    let eventDate = new Date();
    eventDate.setDate(eventDate.getDate());
    let event = new CalendarEvent("XXX", eventDate, eventDate, true);
    this.calEvents.push(event);
    this.mainCalendar.selectedDate = eventDate;
}
```

I am trying to keep today's date selected by default and events under it listed when a user visits the calendar.
Now a user has to click on today's date to see the events under it.

I tried to keep today's date selected using `selectedDate` but it's no working.

Can anyone tell me how to do it? Thanks!

Here's a [playground link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=BtluPA&v=13)

Comment: You will have to wait for the component to be created before accessing it, using loaded event ensures that.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor code should be moved to NgOnInit.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let eventDate = new Date();
    eventDate.setDate(eventDate.getDate());
    let event = new CalendarEvent("XXX", eventDate, eventDate, true);
    this.calEvents.push(event);
    this.mainCalendar.selectedDate = eventDate;
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code in both android and ios. The modification works fine. Have you gotten any exceptions?

Comment: When I move the code to ngOnInit,  get the following error: Property 'selectedDate' does not exist on type 'ElementRef<any>'

Answer (score 0):

try put nativeElement like this:

this.mainCalendar.nativeElement.selectedDate = eventDate;